# How to print a simple 'Select' on excel with a .bat?

Tags: sql, oracle

It's first time that I approach to sql.

For training, I would like create a script, that will be running with a .bat .
The script has to print the result of some count on a excel file.

This is an example of request:

```
select  count(distinct email) as nb_mail,  count(distinct siret) as nb_siret 
from     MY_TABLE
```

i would like have a file excel with two column, one for mail et one for siret.

Can i have un example for the process? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, output into an .xlsx file isn't that easy. To be honest, I don't know how to do it. But, creating a **.CSV** file which can be easily opened by MS Excel isn't that difficult.

**spool_to_csv.SQL file:**

```
set trim on
set echo off
set feedback off
set colsep ';'
spool my_csv.csv

select d.dname, count(*) cnt
from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
group by d.dname
order by d.dname;

spool off;
exit
```

**spool_to_csv.BAT file:**

```
sqlplus -s scott/tiger @spool_to_csv.sql
```

When you run it, the result is (opened in Excel):

[image]

If that's OK with you, use it. If not, I'm afraid I can't help much further.

Comment: Exactly as I showed; your spool_to_csv.sql would have your own SELECT statement.